# REST API- Defining proper and intuitive URI

Tags: rest, http

I'm tring to create a little registration app, that will be published as a REST API. It will allow users / systems to create an account on my system. They will pass in a username and a password. 
According to the rules that i've read, the "/" in a URI must be used to indicate a hierarchical relationship.

So I'm wondering if this type of a URI follows the rules, and is intuitive enough:

```
 POST http://myregistrations.com/users/user/{user_id},{password}
 GET http://myregistrations.com/users/user/{user_id}
 PUT http://myregistrations.com/users/user/{user_id},{password}
 DELETE  http://myregistrations.com/users/user/{user_id}
```

or should i remove the "users" part from the URI?  In that case, if I want to get "all" users, i could just do the following:

```
 GET http://myregistrations.com/user/
 DELETE http://myregistrations.com/user/  ** i might not allow this but just for discussion purposes...
```

And the rest of the methods would look like this:

```
 POST http://myregistrations.com/user/{user_id},{password}
 GET http://myregistrations.com/user/{user_id}
 PUT http://myregistrations.com/user/{user_id},{password}
 DELETE  http://myregistrations.com/user/{user_id}
```

I don't want to over complicate things... but I also want to make sure I follow conventions. 
I am leaning towards the second example, where I don't have "users". Given that each part of the URI should map to an addressable resource, and that I won't be allowing batch updates to accounts, having a concept of "users" seems useless at this time.  I might be missing something though.

Maybe I'm just splitting hairs.  I've been reading other posts here too about defining REST APIs... but I haven't found anything yet.

Thanks.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use both `user` and `users`.  If it were me, I would use `user` for the ones taking a `user-id`, and `users` for the list.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606400/rest-api-design-links-between-collections-of-resources/15296043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically plural is how you reference a resource so `users` in this case and not `user`. This is what you're routes should look like to follow the REST pattern.

```
 POST http://myregistrations.com/users/  --> The post payload should contain: {user_id},{password}
 GET http://myregistrations.com/users/{user_id}  --> The user_id is in the URL
 PUT http://myregistrations.com/users/{user_id}  --> The user_id is in the URL
 DELETE  http://myregistrations.com/users/{user_id} --> The user_id is in the url
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have both concepts (user and users) with a single API. The URI `/users/user` seems convoluted to me.

**Over-simplified example:**

Post one user:

```
POST /user/{user_id,password}
```

Post multiple users:

```
POST /user/[{user_id,password},{user_id,password}]
```

Get one user:

```
GET /user/{user_id}
Response: {user_name} or [{user_name}]
```

Get multiple users:

```
GET /user/{search_user_name}
Response: [{user_name},{user_name},{user_name}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to over complicate things...

I have bad news for you, you've already overcomplicated things. The REST clients know nothing about the URI structure, because they follow hyperlinks annotated with semantic metadata. The clients check this metadata instead of the URI structure.